# Can't install Ubuntu 22.04 alongside with Windows 11

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I have HP Envy x360 laptop with Windows 11 on it. It has AMD Ryzen 7 and AMD graphic card.
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 with USB drive as dual boot but I have no luck so far.

When I try to select '**Try or install Ubuntu**' in grub, I just got stuck on loading screen (with HP logo). Pressing ESC shows the following:

**[1 of 3] A start job is running for Network Name Resolution (time/time)**

**[2 of 3] A start job is running for Userspace Out-Of-Memory (time/time)**

**[3 of 3] A start job is running for Network Time Synchronization (time/time)**

The 'time' is always getting bigger and bigger but nothing happens. It only shows **[FAILED] stopped Userspace Out-Of-Memory** (or other two) and starts again.

What I have already tried:

- Secure boot is disabled
- Fast boot is disabled
- I've tried several different programs for creating bootable USB drive
- Tried to add 'nomodeset' to grub (failed with **[FAILED] Failed to start Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer** and two more errors like this. They are listed above)
- Tried to add amdgpu.dc=0 to grub (failed; my screen just suddenly had some green broken pixels on it and no boot)
- Tried to boot with **Safe Graphics** but got blank screen after several minutes with logo loading.

Let me know if you need more information.

I've been trying to install it for two weeks.
Please, can anybody help me to finally do this?

Comment: Sounds like the ISO you used to make the live media is bad. Did you verify the ISO before making it? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: @David yes, I've already tried to do this, all seems to be fine